# How Can I Use a Method Returning IQueryable<T> in Compiled Linq to SQL Query Without Error

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a method returning an IQueryable that I use in a compiled query.  This method prevents me from having to incorporate a very large linq to sql query repeatedly while modifying just the WHERE clause.  For example, internally we reference these items using a DB-generated identity column so I have one function that takes that the internal id value and returns the object searching on the internal id column. For our web services, we get a different id and I have another function that uses the same underlying query with only the different where clause (or singleordefault, etc.).  All of this works great until I try to use this as a compiled query (which is essential in this case for performance).  When I invoke the compiled query, I receive "The query contains references to items defined on a different data context." with a gigantic stack trace.  Note that this only happens for a certain sequence of execution when this is running on our application server.  If I set up a simple test case that just calls this method it works fine.

My question is, how can I get this working under NET 4.5?  I realize that I was probably "lucky" in NET 4 that this worked since I was using the version of my function that references an instance variable for the datacontext in my dataaccess class.  Here's the original version that worked under 4.0:

```
public IQueryable<Log> GetBaseLogQuery(EncDataContext context)
{
    var query =
        from pl in context.DbLog
        ... (lots of joins and lets)
        select new Log
        {
            LogID = pl.LogId,
            UniqueID = pl.UniqueID,
            ... many other memebers set
        }
    ;
    return query;
}

public IQueryable<Log> GetBaseLogQuery()
{
    return GetBaseQuery(Context); // Context is an instance variable
}

private static Func<EncDataContext, int, string, Log> _loadLogByUniqueId;
public Log LoadLog(int organizationId, string uniqueId)
{
    if (_loadLogByUniqueId == null)
    {
        var query = GetBaseLogQuery();
        _loadLogByUniqueId = CompiledQuery.Compile<EncDataContext, int, string, Log>(
            (context, orgId, uid) => query.SingleOrDefault(pl => pl.OrganizationId == orgId && pl.UniqueID == uid)
        );
    }
    var ret = _loadLogByUniqueId.Invoke(Context, organizationId, uniqueId);
    return ret;
}
```

If I try to use the method and pass it the datacontext directly in the compile like this:

```
_loadLogByUniqueId = CompiledQuery.Compile<EncDataContext, int, string, Log>(
    (context, orgId, uid) => GetBaseLogQuery(context).SingleOrDefault(pl => pl.OrganizationId == orgId && pl.UniqueID == uid)
```

I get a different error -- "Member access 'Int32 LogID' of 'BusinessEntities.Log' not legal on type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[BusinessEntities.Log]."

So after some research people mention needing to expand the method before compile time so that it can be translated into SQL by linq to sql.  However, I'm not able to get this working.  When I try to assign the output of GetBaseLogQuery to an expression so that I can call the LinqKit invoke on it, I get a type mismatch.

Is there any way for me to not have to duplicate the linq to sql query in GetBaseLogQuery in every compiled query I currently use it in?

Comment: try doing it the adder way around compile the GetBaseLogQuery receiving a IQueryable and then expand the IQueryable before passing it to the compiled query.

Comment: let me see lots joins and lets, pls.

Answer (score 0):

Just a random try:

Transform your GetBaseLogQuery function to :

```
Func<EncDataContext,IQueryable<Log>> getBaseLogQuery;
public Expression<Func<EncDataContext,IQueryable<Log>>> GetBaseLogQuery(EncDataContext context)
{
    if(getBaseLogQuery==null)
        getBaseLogQuery=GetBaseLogQueryExpr().Compile();
    return getBaseLogQuery(context);
}

public Expression<Func<EncDataContext,IQueryable<Log>>> GetBaseLogQueryExpr()
{
    return context=>from pl in context.DbLog ..... etc ....; // contrainst: this MUST be a lambda.
}
```

And then, create this function:

```
static Expression<Func<EncDataContext, TArg1, TArg2, TReturn>> WrapQuery<T, TArg1, TArg2, TReturn>(Expression<Func<IQueryable<T>, TArg1, TArg2, TReturn>> todo)
{
    var baseQuery = GetBaseLogQueryExpr();
    var newQueryExpression = new ReplaceVisitor(todo.Parameters.First(), baseQuery.Body).Visit(todo.Body);
    List<ParameterExpression> @params = todo.Parameters.Skip(1).ToList();
    @params.Insert(0, baseQuery.Parameters.First());
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<EncDataContext, TArg1, TArg2, TReturn>>(newQueryExpression, @params.ToArray());
}
```

using class

```
    class ReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        readonly Expression to;
        readonly ParameterExpression @from;

        public ReplaceVisitor(ParameterExpression from, Expression to)
        {
            this.to = to;
            this.@from = @from;
        }

        public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
        {
            if (node == @from)
                return @to;
            return base.Visit(node);
        }
    }
```

You can create your query extension like this:

```
var resultExpr = WrapQuery((query,orgId,uid)=>query.SingleOrDefault(pl =>  pl.OrganizationId == organizationId && pl.UniqueID == uniqueId));
_loadLogByUniqueId = CompiledQuery.Compile(resultExpr);
```

Not tested.

Pros: Can be reused.

Cons: You'll have to rewrite a new WrapQuery function for each parameter count (that's quite easy, though... just a dump copy/paste/adapt)

Comment: @JohnOpincar tell me if it doesnt works... I'll correct it :)

Comment: I'll give that a shot when I have some time.  We just had a major release this weekend so I'm pressed for time.

Comment: I'm going to award the bounty even though this isn't tested yet so the points don't go to waste.

Comment: Thanks :) ... it might require a bit of tweaking, but it should work, though !